# mysql select rows with top max value

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table in **mysql** with columns: `id` , `view` , `agree`.
i have upload my *table*'s image below:

[image]

i want to select 8 rows that **greater** than others in `view` column. my condition is **`agree = 1`**.

can you tell me how can i do it by [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) query or [php](/questions/tagged/php).

Comment: What would happen if there's a 10 way tie on the highest `view` value?

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from table_name WHERE agree = 1 ORDER BY view desc LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE agree = 1 
ORDER BY view DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 1):

use `limit` and `order by`

```
Select * from mytable 
where aggree=1 
ORDER BY view DESC 
LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTableName
WHERE agree = 1
ORDER BY view DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **ORDER BY** clause.

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE AGREE = 1 ORDER BY VIEW DESC LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) for `DESC` or `ASC` sorting.

and For selection of 8 rows use [Limit Data Selections From a MySQL Database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

```
Select * from table_name WHERE agree = 1 ORDER BY view desc LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the top 8 'view' values from the table the MySql query for that is:

```
SELECT  * FROM tablename  WHERE agree=1 ORDER BY view DESC LIMIT 8;
```

Note: Replace tablename with the actual name of your table